# Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray always null

Tags: android, base64, android-bitmap

While trying to decode base64 string and convert it back to an image

Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray

always returns null.here i have mentioned what i am trying.

```
 String base64="9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdC
 IFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQA.....it goes lenthy";

 byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base64.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length, opts);
        cancelceque_img.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

this method i have used to convert base64 to image,any one give me the solution.

Comment: What was the resolution of the jpg image that you base64 encoded?

Comment: Where did you get that base64 string from? From the logcat? Then its incomplete.

Comment: base 64 string getting from backend side @blackapps